# Using a PD USB hub for power and data for Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, power, usb-power, alternative-power, usb-hub

I want to use a 7" LCD (not the official Pi 7" LCD) together with the Pi 4. According to the LCD documentation, it requires 2A. I was planning initially to power the LCD through one Pi.

Now I am thinking about using this [USB PD hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B093BJ4S9P). So I will connect a 5V/5A to the PD port of the hub. LCD display will be powered through the hub and the Pi itself will be connected to the hub at it's micro USB power connection. Here is the connection sketch I have in mind:

[image]

So I would like ask:

-If powering the Pi this way is alright?
-Would Pi be able to access the display's HDMI over USB?
-Would other drives/peripherals on the hub accessible to Pi since the hub is connected to Pi's -power port? I am not sure if it can be used for data as well

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect it to work. There should be a jack/barrel connector to supply the power. The 100W output would be OK to power the Pi via USB-C power port. I do not follow how the HDMI goes through the USB hub to the LCD display, I think it should be HDMI to  HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Powering Pi from USB-C of the hub may work, if it can provide sufficient power (up to 2A depending on peripherals).
2. Connecting Pi to the hub via USB-C won't work. **The USB-C connector on Pi 4 is only for power.**